Need help with MultiaxesArrangement
I'm trying to use different axes for the third of three lines because the difference in scale makes it impossible to see the effects on the third line. However, the resulting graph bunches all of the lines together, and nothing is gained.
san5 = c + t d (a - w)/(3) + 2 r k/(3 (1 - t (1 - a))) + 
   r k /(3 (1 - t (1 - w)));
san6 = c + t 2 d (a - w)/(3) + 2 r k/(3 (1 - t (1 - w))) + 
   r k /(3 (1 - t (1 - a)));
san7 = 1/3 (1 + (k r)/(d (1 + (-1 + a) t) (1 + t (-1 + w)))) 
ListLinePlot[{Table[(san5 /. {d -> 1, a -> 1, r -> .1, k -> 1, 
      t -> .2, c -> 1}), {w, 0, 1, .01}], 
  Table[(san6 /. {d -> 1, a -> 1, r -> .1, k -> 1, t -> .2, 
      c -> 1}), {w, 0, 1, .01}], 
  Table[san7/. {d ->
       1, a -> 1, r -> .1, k -> 1, t -> .2, c -> 1}, {w, 0, 1, .01}]},
  MultiaxisArrangement -> {{1, 2}, {3}}]



    Clear["Global`*"];
    {d, a, r, k, t, c} = {1, 1, 0.1, 1, 0.2, 1};
    san5[w_] = 
      c + t d (a - w)/(3) + 2 r k/(3 (1 - t (1 - a))) + 
       r k/(3 (1 - t (1 - w)));
    san6[w_] = 
      c + t 2 d (a - w)/(3) + 2 r k/(3 (1 - t (1 - w))) + 
       r k/(3 (1 - t (1 - a)));
    san7[w_] = 1/3 (1 + (k r)/(d (1 + (-1 + a) t) *(1 + t (-1 + w))));
    Plot [{san5[w], san6[w], san7[w]}, {w, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}, AxesLabel -> {w, san__}]
Plot [{10 san7[w]}, {w, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}, AxesLabel -> {w, san__}]

As the slope of San7 is small,  y-axis range multiplied 10 times for convenience.


